# UIButton in Navigation Bar Not Recognizing Taps in iOS 11

Tags: uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem, ios11

I have a `UIButton` in a navigation bar that sits over the top of a `UIImage` and a `UILabel`. It worked fine in iOS 10, but now in iOS 11 it doesn't recognize any taps from my `@IBAction` outlet.

[image: navbar button]

I tried moving the tap outlet to the bar button item, but that didn't work either. The `UIButton` has the following constraints:

[image]

I confirmed that it's there by giving it a green background, so I know it's visible and available.

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: same problem with UIBarButtonItem :( try find solution...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found a solution from another developer.

You have to add width and height constraints to the view that wraps all your stuff inside the bar button item. So in my case, the item labeled `View` needs the constraints.

Here's what to do:

**Step 1**

Create an `@IBOutlet` from `View` to the view controller that has this nav bar.

```
@IBOutlet weak var myView: UIView!
```

**Step 2**

In the containing view controller, inside `viewDidLoad()` add the constraints:

```
myView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 63).isActive = true
myView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 33).isActive = true
```

After that, everything works like it used to.

Comment: Yes it worked for me. Setting constraints for all views that are added to bar button items is the trick for this

Comment: This also works for the similar situation where you put a button in the navigationItem's titleView. Very unintuitive, but thanks!

Comment: When you inspect the debug view hierarchy in Xcode - if you cannot see the view containing the elements (buttons or views) in your custom navigation item, then this fix should solve your issue. At least it did for me.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Clifton Labrum, this is the way to go. Apple changed the way navigation bars work in iOS 11. 
This can also be done in Storyboard but through descendant constraints.

The Custom view inside UIBarButtonItem can NOT be given constraints directly. Instead, provide its subviews with constraints, and the Custom view will get its constraints implicitly:

[image: UIButton has its constraints]

[image: UIButton Constraints]

The custom view will implicitly get its size because of those constraints.

This should fix all the weird behavior caused by iOS 11.

Comment: This is a great option without needing any code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

it's crazy but:
in my situation i have custom NavBar with NavBarItems (rigth button in my case) and **IMPORTANT**: programmatically added UITapGestureRecognizer(for dismiss keyboard on tap around a textfield):

```
let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(dismissKeyboard))
view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

on iOS 10.3 - all be ok... on 11 - i have only my "tap" action... so when i dismiss TapGestureRecognizer - actions on NavBar  start working...

so, if you have some gestures on you screen - just try remove it...

hope it's help for you