# IOS 11 navigation item with user interaction enabled not working

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios11

Hi i have navigation item in there is a view which contains two labels i have added userInteractionEnabled for the view inside the navigation element (IBoutleted as navigationView)

```
navigationView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

mainTitleClicked = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(mainTitleTapped))

self.navigationView.addGestureRecognizer(mainTitleClicked)
```

This was working in IOS 10 but when i run the same code in xcode 9 ios 11 UI is messed up and gesture is not getting recognised

[image]

IOS 10 Version

[image]

IOS 11 version

What should i change to make it work on ios 11

Thanks for the help

Comment: can you add some additional code

Comment: I suggest looking into safeAreaLayoutGuide - It may help

Comment: add the back ground color and check once

Comment: what code should i add

Comment: strange background color change is working in ios 10 but 11

Comment: Not sure if this is relavent, but this answer put me on the right path. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46306796/uibutton-in-navigation-bar-not-recognizing-taps-in-ios-11/46325661#46325661

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solved it By adding the following code

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
        self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
        var width = navigationView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).width - 15.0
        let height = navigationView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height

        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let windowWidth = screenSize.width
        width = windowWidth * 0.55

        let widthConstraint = navigationView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
        let heightConstraint = navigationView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)

        heightConstraint.isActive = true
        widthConstraint.isActive = true
    }
```

Making height and width constraint active was a answer given in another question i currently don't have the link to it will post the link in the edit (Currently i am unable to find that question)

Answer (score 0):

I have this same problem and solved with this code too:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = false
            self.navigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .automatic
            var width = popUserChatView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).width - 15.0
            let height = popUserChatView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude)).height


            let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
            let windowWidth = screenSize.width
            width = windowWidth * 0.55

            let widthConstraint = popUserChatView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: width)
            let heightConstraint = popUserChatView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: height)

            heightConstraint.isActive = true
            widthConstraint.isActive = true
        }
```

calling in ViewDidLoad()